# I may go VS I would go

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence, writing

''I … not go there because it will be hot and crowded'' which one is correct 'may' or 'would', or both are correct but have different meanings?

I think ‘may’ is correct, but people told me that ‘would’ is also correct. The problem is that 'would' is in the past, and there is no *if clause* in the sentence, so why is it correct to use in the sentence?

Comment: Practically any modal auxiliary would go there because they like hot and crowded contexts. _I would/could/should/might/must/can/will/may not go there_ are all grammatical, though they all mean different things, and not all of them refer to being hot and crowded in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both correct; they have different meanings.

"I may not go" implies that there is a concrete opportunity in front of you, but you are undecided.

"I would not go" implies a hypothetical situation, but if it were real, you would definitely decline.

If the sentence has to end with "it will be hot and crowded", and not "it would be hot and crowded", "I would not go" sounds weird unless your invitation to this event is hypothetical, like

> Person A: My cousin is getting married at Disneyland
>
> Person B: I wouldn't go to that, it'll be hot and crowded.

As opposed to

> Person A: My cousin is getting married in Disneyland. I may not go
> because it will be hot and crowded.

But again, the sentence there also implies that the person might end up going after all, but if they do not, it is because it will be hot and crowded.

EDIT: I guess I should add that in written English "I may not go" might also mean "I am not permitted to go", but in spoken English, at least in America, that usage sounds stuffy and overly formal, and "I can't go" would be used instead. (Even though that usage is ambiguous as to whether the obstacle is merely permission, or something more substantial)

Comment: Thank you so much! this is the most useful answer I have found so far. The problem is that I have this sentence in an exercise, and I don't want to argue with the teacher over which one is correct because I know it depends on the mood of the speaker, so do you think 'may' is the safest option here?

Comment: Because of "will" in the second half of the sentence, I'd say "May".  Without more context, mixing "would" and "will" together would not be right.

Comment: All right. Thank you so much for your help.